# How to disable a toast messages in my app?

Tags: android, toast

I am building an Othello game (human play with bot). In my program have no any Toast command and infinite loop, my game just takes a long time to compute for each next move of my bot (I am trying to make my bot more smarter). Because of some unclear reason, the system always show an empty message by toast and error message in logcat as below and I don't want to see its appearance. How can I disable it, or all Toast message?

[image]

In logcat:

```
Package has already posted 50 toasts. Not showing more
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Android wont show Toast messages untill you call the toast function. Search for “Toast” in your project you will find something

Comment: can you try on other devices/emulators? do they have the same problem. show   your dependencies from your grade file.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, it still appear on other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a third-party library that creates toasts.
You can use `Find in path` or `Find usages` in Android Studio to find where the toasts are being displayed.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to find toast command in my code and I sure that it is not exists in my code and I do not use a third-party library to show toast message.

Comment: A third party library may be trying to show toast messages erroneously.
Can you share a list of dependencies you are using?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, while not find a better solution, is to manually enter to your device settings and block notifications from your app, this will block annoying toasts.

You can also invoke your app notifications settings screen with the code (expanded to support all android versions) and maybe later implement a sharedprefs routine to show it only first time at all (to avoid open settings every time you open the app):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
    intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", context.getPackageName());
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
    intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
} else {
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
}

yourContext.startActivity(intent);
```

P.S.: Please, check this answer as correct if you think it was helpful to address you question. T.Y.

Answer (score 0):

Select the main package in android studio, then ctrl+shift+f to search through all your packages and classes, then write "toast.show" to find the toast that is written in your code